# Robotium test - Call activity after finish

Tags: loops, testing, robotium

I am using do-while loop to test my app via robotium. I wanted to repeat the login screen 4-5 times.

But after finish, it not able to start the app again. It is just showing this process only one time.
Can anyone help?

Comment: just write 4-5 test methods

Comment: use do { /*your steps*/ } while(i < 5), where the i is the number of iterrations

Comment: Can you please paste your code into your question, i have a feeling you are calling a method that you should not be, or are not restarting your activity each loop.